# Facing an Forgerock object execption in OpenDJ Reset password with OPenAM

Tags: ldap, openam, opendj, forgerock

I have been facing this issue while resetting the password through open-DJ(apache directory).

Getting a exception message stated that

```
The LDAP password modify operation failed with result code 65
Error Message:  Entry
uid=ssssa2020@gmail.com,ou=people,dc=uppclwallet,dc=com cannot be modified
because the resulting entry would have violated the server schema: Entry
uid=sssa2020@gmail.com,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
 **violates the
Directory Server schema **configuration** because it contains an unknown
objectclass wallet**
```

I have tried this command to reset the password in opendj

```
./ldappasswordmodify -h hostname -p 1389 -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w We@123 \
  --authzID uid=ssssa2020@gmail.com,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com \
  --newPassword Qwerty@1
```

I have tried using openAM/openDJ or ldapmodify command to reset the password. but getting same execption.

Attached the image for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

The error is well explained in the error message. The entry you are trying to modify (even though just changing the password), is not compliant with the server's schema. It contains an unknown objectClass: "wallet".

OpenDJ will always verify that entries are compliant with the schema on updates. The compliance may be broken if schema definitions are removed but entries not cleaned, or if you've imported data with schema checking disabled. Also, schema may not be properly replicated between servers (mostly due to mistakes in schema change handling).

If you fix the server's schema, or first remove the objectClass from the entry, you will be able to change the user's password.